# Two 'app' tags on stackapps.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackapps

One of the stackapps.com entries on the home page has two [app] tags: [Stack Monthly - Best questions in the month](https://stackapps.com/questions/2446/stack-monthly-best-questions-in-the-month).

[image: Two app tags on stackapps.com]

Comment: This is how [Magnitude](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-_4mcYsQdE "where's wally?") tags questions

Comment: [I don't see anything wrong with this.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4rkTc.jpg)

Comment: Both of those links are creepy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bad tag specified in the metadata on this post, it's been corrected and shows as `app` + `python` now.